# Ember.js -- how to console log a model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Pretty general question here. In my code I am frequently dealing with models:

```
let model = this.currentModel;
```

Which seems to be working, but if I

```
console.log(model);
```

I see this useless code in the console:

```
<lc-dash@model:bizinfo::ember904:null>
```

Does anyone know how to actually log the contents of the model as an object? Also, anywhere I can read about the meaning of this tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to actually log the contents of the model as an object?

The ember data models have a [toJSON](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_toJSON) method that extracts the relevant data for you:

```
console.log(model.toJSON());
```

This method uses the [JSONSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html) to create the JSON representation.

If you want to log the data in a more app-specific way, you can use [serialize](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_serialize):

```
model.serialize();
```

which uses the serialization strategy you defined in the store's adapter to create a JSON representation of the model.

> Also, anywhere I can read about the meaning of this tag?

All objects in an Ember app, including Ember Data models, inherit from [Ember.CoreObject](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CoreObject.html), which has a [toString](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CoreObject.html#method_toString) method that prints this representation.

```
<lc-dash@model:bizinfo::ember904:null>
```

means:

- `lc-dash` is your app name
- `model` is the ember type of the object you are logging (can be controller, route etc.)
- `bizinfo` is the name of the object you are logging (name of your model, or controller, or route etc.)
- `ember904` is a guId create with [Ember.guidFor](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_guidFor)
- `null` is the model's id. You can overwrite this value using the method `toStringExtension` in your particular model

For comparison example, here's how logging your application controller would look:

```
<lc-dash@controller:application::ember324>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)